# How to find Whether the network available in any device is EDGE or WiFi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to find Whether  the network available in any device is EDGE or WiFi  ??

Thanks in Advance 
Ranganatha  G V

Answer (score 1):

Check the [reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample from apple.